# Intertwine time-series data from different data sources in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 data sources:

Source 1:

```
x,y,z,timestamp
1,2,3,1526867601  // Discarded
2,2,4,1526867602 // Discarded
3,2,5,1526867603
4,2,6,1526867604
5,2,7,1526867605
6,2,8,1526867606
8,2,9,1526867607 // Discarded
9,3,3,1526867608 // Discarded
10,3,3,1526867609
11,3,3,1526867610
12,3,3,1526867611
```

Source 2:

```
event,timestamp
start,1526867603
stop,1526867606
start,1526867609
stop,1526867611
```

Expected output after filtering `source 1` against `source 2`:

```
3,2,5,1526867603
4,2,6,1526867604
5,2,7,1526867605
6,2,8,1526867606
10,3,3,1526867609
11,3,3,1526867610
12,3,3,1526867611
```

As you can see, `Source 2` will create a bunch of time intervals. I want to be able to filter for rows in `Source 1` whose timestamp value falls in any of the valid time intervals mentioned..

I've tried using Tableau Prep and Tableau Desktop but couldn't figure out a way to do filtering on multiple sources.. Please help!

Comment: your data structures are not very clear, could you provide the structure and the desired output with some sample data?

Comment: Hi @HakanERDOGAN is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, it is very clear now, thanks! This seems to be problem of finding that "discarded" flag rather than filtering with multiple data sources. It is easy after getting that flag or the opposite "filter-in" flag. If I were you, I would not do that part in Tableau but use a tool like Excel. I would first convert Source2 to a structure that the start and stop timestamps are on the same rows. After that, we may use a COUNTIFS formula to see whether Source1 rows are within intervals of Source2. Then we may get that "flagged" Source1 data to Tableau and filter with that new field.